# Running 'php artisan migrate:fresh' in Laravel code

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

Is it possible to run `php artisan migrate:fresh` in the actual Laravel code without the shell? For example before loading the table factories in this function.

```
Route::get('/seed', function () {
    // php artisan migrate:fresh
    factory(App\User::class)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Campaign::class, 20)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Model::class, 200)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Trim::class, 400)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Color::class, 800)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Specification::class, 800)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Option::class, 800)->create();
    factory(App\Models\LeaseLength::class, 800)->create();
    factory(App\Models\Mileage::class, 800)->create();
    factory(App\Models\ExtraOption::class, 800)->create();

    return redirect()->back();
});
```

The goal for this would be to clean the tables before seeding it again.

Comment: Yes, did you read the documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: Do you want to Run artisan command from your controller or route, without shell?

Comment: ^ That doesn't matter... The link I posted actually says "*For example, you may wish to fire an Artisan command from a **route or controller.**"*. The `Artisan` facade is available anywhere in Laravel.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. adding `Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');` and importing it worked for me.

Comment: No problem! Just a note; be careful how you use this. You probably don't want this route accessible by anyone... `php artisan migrate:fresh` nukes all data in your database and rebuilds it, and should be run with caution in a real-world situation. Having it available via a simple `GET` request throws the caution out the window :)

Comment: @TimLewis Yes! I currently have it because this application is still in early development. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run `artisan` command from your controller like this

```
use Artisan;

public function artisan()
   {
       Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');
       Artisan::call('make:seeder UsersTableSeeder');
       Artisan::call('config:clear');
   }
```